# Wait for some Spring ListenableFuture

Tags: spring, completable-future, spring-web, asyncresttemplate

There is a service which uses Spring `AsyncRestTemplate` for sending rest calls. Each call of `AsyncRestTemplate.exchange()` returns `ListenableFuture`. Something like this:

```
    ListenableFuture future1 = new AsyncRestTemplate().exchange(...);
    ListenableFuture future2 = new AsyncRestTemplate().exchange(...);
    ListenableFuture future3 = new AsyncRestTemplate().exchange(...);
```

Is there a way for create single `ListenableFuture` which combines all other calls? Something like `Futures.allAsList` from Guava.

Comment: Your best bet is to use an adapter like this one: [Future Converter](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter)

Answer (score 3):

Step #1: Convert each ListenableFuture to CompletableFuture

```
public CompletableFuture<T> toCompletableFuture(ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> listenableFuture) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
            completableFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
            completableFuture.complete(parseResponse(result));
            }
        }
    });
    return completableFuture;
}
```

Step #2: call CompletableFuture.allOf(cF1, cF2, cF3...)

Comment: in spring 5 there is org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture#completable method which does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring 5.0, `ListenableFuture` implements the method `completable()` which does exactly what you need:

```
    /**
     * Expose this {@link ListenableFuture} as a JDK {@link CompletableFuture}.
     * @since 5.0
     */
    default CompletableFuture<T> completable() {
```